# How should I drop blocks of NAs from an R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large R `data.table` with a multi column key, where some value columns contain some NA. I'd like to remove groups that are entirely NA in one or more value columns, but keep the whole group otherwise. Repeating this for each column of the key.

To give a simplified example:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(
    Series = rep(letters[1:12], each = 3), 
    Id = 1:12,
    Value1 = c(1:3, NA, 5:9, rep(NA,3), 1:3, NA, 5:9, rep(NA,3), 1:3, NA, 5:9, rep(NA,3)), 
    Value2 = c(rep(NA,3), 1:4, NA, 6:9, rep(NA,3), 1:9, 1:9, rep(NA,3)))
DT
    Series Id Value1 Value2
 1:      a  1      1     NA
 2:      a  2      2     NA
 3:      a  3      3     NA
 4:      b  4     NA      1
 5:      b  5      5      2
 6:      b  6      6      3
 7:      c  7      7      4
 8:      c  8      8     NA
 9:      c  9      9      6
10:      d 10     NA      7
11:      d 11     NA      8
12:      d 12     NA      9
13:      e  1      1     NA
14:      e  2      2     NA
15:      e  3      3     NA
16:      f  4     NA      1
17:      f  5      5      2
18:      f  6      6      3
19:      g  7      7      4
20:      g  8      8      5
21:      g  9      9      6
22:      h 10     NA      7
23:      h 11     NA      8
24:      h 12     NA      9
25:      i  1      1      1
26:      i  2      2      2
27:      i  3      3      3
28:      j  4     NA      4
29:      j  5      5      5
30:      j  6      6      6
31:      k  7      7      7
32:      k  8      8      8
33:      k  9      9      9
34:      l 10     NA     NA
35:      l 11     NA     NA
36:      l 12     NA     NA
    Series Id Value1 Value2
```

So I would like to drop:

- Series: a,d,e,h and l
- Ids: 4, 10,11 and 12

Correct result should look like:

```
    Series Id Value1 Value2
 1:      b  5      5      2
 2:      b  6      6      3
 3:      c  7      7      4
 4:      c  8      8     NA
 5:      c  9      9      6
 6:      f  5      5      2
 7:      f  6      6      3
 8:      g  7      7      4
 9:      g  8      8      5
10:      g  9      9      6
11:      i  1      1      1
12:      i  2      2      2
13:      i  3      3      3
14:      j  5      5      5
15:      j  6      6      6
16:      k  7      7      7
17:      k  8      8      8
18:      k  9      9      9
    Series Id Value1 Value2
```

---

What I managed so far:

I can find the Series that are NA for Value1 like this:

```
DT[, sum(1-is.na(Value1)) == 0, by = Series][V1 == TRUE]
```

And I could even do

```
setkey(DT, Series)
DT = DT[DT[, sum(1-is.na(Value)) == 0, by = Series][V1 != TRUE]]
```

But now I end up with V1 appearing in the final table.

Comment: why not just `na.omit(DT)`?

Comment: `na.omit` is just removing all the NAs.  I only want to remove when the entire "block" is NA.  So in the example, there are no value for m or z, so they should be dropped, but I don't want to drop the two NAs in series b

Comment: Then @Arun has your answer, but you shouldn't need `as.logical`.

Comment: Interesting, `DT[, .SD[all(!is.na(Value))], by=Series]` works fine.

Comment: Just did a large edit to try make the question clearer and use a better/simpler example.  From Arun's answer is looks like .SD is the way to go, presumable a logical or can sort out multiple Value columns, but how do I do multiple key columns.  Is the only way to do them one at a time?  (Since I can't have two keys at once)

Comment: @Corone Great edit, +1. I edited the first paragraph a little further. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes thanks @Matthew that's exactly what I meant

Comment: @Carone Great. I edited Arun's answer to make it a full solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this to get those entries where not ALL `Value` are `NA`:

```
setkey(DT, "Series")
DT[, .SD[(!all(is.na(Value)))], by=Series]
```

The parens around `!all` are needed to avoid not-join syntax which Matthew will look into (see comments). Same as this :

```
DT[, .SD[as.logical(!all(is.na(Value)))], by=Series]
```

---

Building on that to answer the new clarified question :

```
allNA = function(x) all(is.na(x))     # define helper function
for (i in c("Id","Series"))
    DT = DT[, if (!any(sapply(.SD,allNA))) .SD else NULL, by=i]
DT
    Series Id Value1 Value2
 1:      i  1      1      1
 2:      i  2      2      2
 3:      i  3      3      3
 4:      b  5      5      2
 5:      b  6      6      3
 6:      f  5      5      2
 7:      f  6      6      3
 8:      j  5      5      5
 9:      j  6      6      6
10:      c  7      7      4
11:      c  8      8     NA
12:      c  9      9      6
13:      g  7      7      4
14:      g  8      8      5
15:      g  9      9      6
16:      k  7      7      7
17:      k  8      8      8
18:      k  9      9      9
```

That changes the order, though. So isn't precisely the result requested. The following keeps the order and should be faster too.

```
# starting fresh from original DT in question again
DT[,drop:=FALSE]
for (i in c("Series","Id"))
    DT[,drop:=drop|any(sapply(.SD,allNA)),by=i]
DT[(!drop)][,drop:=NULL][]
    Series Id Value1 Value2
 1:      b  5      5      2
 2:      b  6      6      3
 3:      c  7      7      4
 4:      c  8      8     NA
 5:      c  9      9      6
 6:      f  5      5      2
 7:      f  6      6      3
 8:      g  7      7      4
 9:      g  8      8      5
10:      g  9      9      6
11:      i  1      1      1
12:      i  2      2      2
13:      i  3      3      3
14:      j  5      5      5
15:      j  6      6      6
16:      k  7      7      7
17:      k  8      8      8
18:      k  9      9      9
```

Comment: +1 `!` = not join, but I'm not sure why it wouldn't work (shouldn't make a difference for logical, may be a prob of not join in combination with recycling, perhaps)

Comment: Okay, now I understand. `.SD[(!all(is.na(Value)))]` (with the paranthesis) works!

Comment: parens does the same to stop the not-join interpretation of `!`. When you say didn't work, what you mean, and which version of data.table please?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that works much better than what I had, but any idea how to extend it to multiple columns?

Comment: `setkey(DT,Series)[unique(DT[,na.omit(Value),by=Series][,Series]),]` does work too. But I can't be bothered to create a big data.table for benchmarking.

Comment: @Arun Thanks a lot. That error message looks strange. A side issue I realise, but I'll take a look.

Answer (score 9):

What about using `complete.cases` function ?

```
DT[complete.cases(DT),]
```

It will drop the rows that have a column value with NA

```
> DT[complete.cases(DT),]
    Series Id Value1 Value2
 1:      b  4      4      1
 2:      b  5      5      2
 3:      b  6      6      3
 4:      c  7      7      4
 5:      c  8      8      5
 6:      c  9      9      6
 7:      f  4      4      1
 8:      f  5      5      2
 9:      f  6      6      3
10:      g  7      7      4
11:      g  8      8      5
12:      g  9      9      6
13:      j  4      4      1
14:      j  5      5      2
15:      j  6      6      3
16:      k  7      7      4
17:      k  8      8      5
18:      k  9      9      6
```

Comment: Nice function, useful to know, but I want a "notempty.cases" function - Only drop those cases that are completely empty for one column, and leave the other NAs in.

Comment: ok, then you should maybe change the dataset example, because all variables that have NA values, have NA values for the 3 rows of the same letter (in both Value1 and value2)