# Remove rows with NA from data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to remove all rows of a `data.table` that contain `Inf` in any of its columns. So far, I've been using this approach:

```
DT <- data.table(col1 = c(1,2,3), col2 = c(4,Inf,5))
DT[,drop := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) any(is.infinite(x))), by = 1:nrow(DT)]
DT <- DT[(!drop)][,drop:=NULL]
```

which comes from [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362614/how-should-i-drop-blocks-of-nas-from-an-r-data-table). However, this approach is not well scalable to large amounts of data. Is there a better way to remove the rows with `Inf`?

Comment: May be `DT[DT[, Reduce('&', lapply(.SD, is.finite))]]`

Comment: Interestingly (?), the example given by the OP doesn't work with version 1.9.5, when @akrun solution works.

Comment: Why not use `rowSums`:  `DT[is.finite(rowSums(DT))]`

Comment: Related: deleting rows by reference might some day be doable in `data.table` http://stackoverflow.com/a/10791729/1191259

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` to check if any element of a row is not finite.

```
DT[is.finite(rowSums(DT))]
```

OR you can use the fact that `Inf * 0` is `NA` and use `complete.cases`

```
DT[complete.cases(DT*0)]
```

Some benchmarking shows that the `rowSums` is fastest for smaller datasets and `complete.cases` is the fastest solution for larger datasets.

```
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  DT[is.finite(rowSums(DT))]
  ,
  DT[complete.cases(DT*0)]
  ,
  DT[DT[, Reduce('&', lapply(.SD, is.finite))]]
)
##
## nrow(DT) = 3000
## Unit: microseconds                                          
##                                          expr       min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
##                     DT[is.finite(rowSums(DT))]  786.797  839.235  864.0215  852.8465  884.756 1021.988   100 a  
##                     DT[complete.cases(DT * 0)] 1265.658 1326.575 1363.3985 1350.0055 1386.377 1898.040   100   c
##  DT[DT[, Reduce("&", lapply(.SD, is.finite))]] 1220.137 1275.030 1319.6226 1308.0555 1348.443 1624.023   100  b 
##
## nrow(DT) = 300000
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                           expr       min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
##                     DT[is.finite(rowSums(DT))] 21.617935 22.687452 26.698070 25.75765 26.07942 87.56290   100   c
##                     DT[complete.cases(DT * 0)]  7.209252  7.567393  9.908503 10.17569 10.37473 71.31375   100 a  
##  DT[DT[, Reduce("&", lapply(.SD, is.finite))]] 11.786773 12.647652 14.128624 14.78512 15.05089 15.39542   100  b
```